# Custom user registration with ajax doesn't work (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created custom user registration using [SimpleCrypto library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleCrypto/). It works fine on its own page (controller `UserController`, action `Registration`, view `Registration`). Then I would like to make this registration in modal window on main page using ajax.

I created partial view **_Registration.cshtml**

```
@model TaskManager.Models.RegisterUserModel

<div class="modal fade" id="registrationModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h2 class="modal-title">Registration</h2>
        </div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "registration-form", id = "registration-form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="modal-body">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Name)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Name, null, new { @class = "error" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Email, null, new { @class = "error" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password, null, new { @class = "error" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
            </div>
        }

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and added it on home page

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registrationModal">registration</a>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/User/_Registration.cshtml")
```

it's my **.js** file

```
/* -------------- DOM READY -------------- */
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";

var $body = $("body");

var ajaxRegistration = function () {
    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    console.log(options);
    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        console.log("ok");
    })
   .fail(function () {
       console.log("error");
   });

    return false;
};
$("#registration-form").submit(ajaxRegistration);
});
```

And it's my **UserController**

```
namespace TaskManager.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        TaskManagerDbContext _db = new TaskManagerDbContext();

        [HttpGet]
        [AjaxAction]
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            var registerUser = new RegisterUserModel();
            return PartialView("_Registration", registerUser);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AjaxAction]
        public ActionResult Registration(RegisterUserModel registerUser)
        {            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!IsUserExist(registerUser.Email))
                {    

                    var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

                    var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(registerUser.Password);

                    var newUser = _db.Users.Create();

                    newUser.Name = registerUser.Name;
                    newUser.Email = registerUser.Email;
                    newUser.Type = UserType.User.ToString();

                    newUser.Password = encrpPass;
                    newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

                    _db.Users.Add(newUser);
                    _db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Task");

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "User already exists");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is incorrect");
            }

            return PartialView("_Registration", registerUser);
        }

        private bool IsUserExist(string email)
        {
            bool IsValid = false;

            var user = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);

            if (user != null)
            {
                IsValid = true;
            }

            return IsValid;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_db != null)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

It works and adds user in database and shows errors in modal window if any field of form is not valid (empty or incorrect data).
But at the same time there are some problems I can't fix.

First of all, if `ModelState.IsValid` is not true or if `IsUserExist(registerUser.Email)` return true, I don't get any errors in my form, `ModelState.AddModelError("", "User already exists");` and `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Неправильные данные");` don't work.

And the second one, if user was registered successfully, redirect `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Task");` doesn't work, I don't know why.

How to fix these bugs?

Comment: But you use only console.log("ok"); You need to replace current window with what you get from the server. Is it the case?

Comment: Actually it's my first attempt to create something so I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: Well, I don't think I need to replace something though. I need to show error somehow if model state is not valid or if user already exists or redirect to other page if registration was successful.

Comment: Well, when you say smt like return PartialView("_Registration", registerUser); the server returns you your view. The same as @Html.Partial("~/Views/User/_Registration.cshtml"). If you say before ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is incorrect"); then your view will contain errors rendered. So if you want to stick to ModelState then you need to get all the HTML and render it again. Or you can send an error and catch it in .fail() method of $.ajax() and show some error message

Comment: Can you explain me please how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible (and rather simple) option: in your controller you do smt like

```
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!IsUserExist(registerUser.Email))
                { 
                    // bad here
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Task");
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK); //at least
                }
                else
                {
                  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "User already exists");
                }
            }
            else
            {
               return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Data is incorrect");
            }
```

And then in js say the following. I use these 2 options, success and error, so you can remove methods done and fail.

```
var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
        success: function() {/*redirect here*/},
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.statusText); /* show the error */
        }
    };
```

As for redirecting. Again, ajax does not expect to be redirected. That's why you need to redirect manually when you get a successful case.

Comment: Is there any way to show  `statusDescription` on page somewhere?

Comment: $("#description").text(statusDescription) ? This is pseudocode of course:)

Comment: Actully I'm not sure, maybe I should return not `HttpStatusCodeResult` but some other result  type here? `return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`, for example? To send code and message on the page?

Comment: Absolutely, that works. Just note that now you need to process everything in 'success' branch of $.ajax.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to return `JsonResult` result.